# How to stop Word 2011 opening hyperlinks on click?

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2011

In previous versions of MS Word, there was a preference for the action to be taken when the user clicked a hyperlink: open it, or edit it. Word 2011 appears to have defaulted to opening the hyperlink, and I can't find the preference to change this behaviour.

How can I change Word's default behaviour when a hyperlink is clicked to be editing the text of the hyperlink? Holding down a modifier key when clicking is not an acceptable solution, as the aim here is to prevent misclicks from causing web pages to open.

**Edit**: the links need to stay as links in the saved document. But when clicked *on my machine*, they should not open. Word needs to default to just editing the link, so an inaccurate click does not take me out of the document into Safari. Older versions of Word had a preference controlling this, and Microsoft seem to have removed it and fixed the behavior at the unsafe option in order to satisfy the point-and-drool crowd.

Comment: Did you tried this as [How to geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16346/how-to-remove-hyperlinks-from-microsoft-word-documents/) explained. Or you can try press `Ctrl+A`, which will highlight the entire text and then
press `Ctrl+Shift+F9` (OR `Ctrl+6`), and you will see all links disappearing within seconds

Comment: By the way which OS you have?

Comment: I'm on Mac OS 10.8.2, and removing the hyperlinks is not the right answer; I'm looking to have them not open when clicked.

Answer (score 2):

I went looking for this for the same reason - it isn't on the preferences menus anywhere.  Just by chance, I discovered that if you use Ctrl+Click (the default for Windows), it doesn't open the link when you click.  My links were behind pictures not words, but I would suspect it'll work the same way.

Comment: On my Mac with Word 15, Alt+Click seems to work best. Ctrl+Click opens a context menu.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your solution lies in a feature called "Field Codes". I looked this up in the built-in Help files on my Mac running Office 2011. Essentially what it boils down to is that Word can actually translate a sort of "code" into your hyperlinks, much like Excel translates a formula into meaningful data. The formula is still there, editable, in the background, but you only see the result of the formula. In Word, hyperlinks are created with field codes, which lie editable in the background, but show a clickable link. If you use the key combination 'Option + F9' (making sure you either have your keyboard set up to use the Function keys as normal, or using the key combination 'Option + FN + F9'), then it switches your view so you see the field code rather than the hyperlink, but you can switch right back and when someone else opens it, they *should* see a clickable hyperlink, since you've only changed the view option temporarily on your own machine.

A field code for a hyperlink looks like this:

`{ HYPERLINK "mailto:someone@email.com" }`

or

`{ HYPERLINK "http://www.website.org/" }`

They're tricky to put in manually, because there's some hidden syntax or something, so you're probably better off just typing it in normally, letting Word change it automatically, and then changing your view so that you can edit the address if you need to. You can also right-click on the individual links and select "Toggle Field Codes" to do one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

How about going to the end of where the hyperlink is and pressing backdelete, to remove the link aspect of it

Another way is copy/paste the link into notepad then back into msword. Then don't push ENTER after it.  If you want a new line or more after it, and you don't already have them, then make  the new lines before you paste the link in. So the link is there but it comes out as plain text and you have new lines after it if need be.

So, when a link is there, you make sure it doesn't go blue and start looking like a link detected by Ms Word, otherwise if it is clicked it will open.

I've tested it in Word 2003.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't answer the question — the hyperlinks need to stay in the document. Also, you've given Windows-specific answers for a Mac program — there is no Notepad on Mac OS :)

Comment: ah you didn't mention mac. By the way, do you want to hover over it and see the address but to click it doesn't go anywhere?   What do you gain from it being a (hyper)link, if you don't want the link to jump anywhere?

Comment: When I send the document (a CV) to recruiters, I want them to be able to click the link to my portfolio. When *I* am editing the document, I want to be able to edit it, not keep opening browser windows — that is, the behaviour on my machine shouldn't be the same for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if Word 2011 for Mac is the equivalent of Word 2010 for Windows. 
 
 If so, check **Word Options > Advanced > Use Ctrl + Click to follow hyperlinks**. It should be selected so that hyperlinks will not open when you click on them.
 
 If you have such an option and select it then hyperlinks in your document will be opened with **Ctrl + Left Click**, if it is not selected hyperlinks will open when you click on them.
 
 Hope this helps.

Comment: option not available on mac